# PHP Include HELP

Tags: php, include

I am in need of some assistance with my PHP include coding. Here is the code I will be speaking about:

```
<?php 
$default = 'about'; //Whatever default page you want to display if the file doesn't exist or you've just arrived to the home page. 
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : $default; //Checks if ?p is set, and puts the page in and if not, it goes to the default page. 
$page = basename($page); //Gets the page name only, and no directories. 
if (!file_exists('content/'.$page.'.php'))    { //Checks if the file doesn't exist 
    $page = $default; //If it doesn't, it'll revert back to the default page 
    //NOTE: Alternatively, you can make up a 404 page, and replace $default with whatever the page name is. Make sure it's still in the inc/ directory. 
} 
include('content/'.$page.'.php'); //And now it's on your page! 
?>
```

Okay, this will call "about.php" as my index page, due to the coding following it. However, I would like for the default index page to call a url page, like "http://www.mywebsite.com/frontpage/". I've tried replacing 'about' with a url, and it just adds on the '.php' extension to the end of the url, and '/content' to the beginning of the url. Because of this, I receive a PHP error.

Can someone assist me with a code that would do what I want to actually do (as discussed above)? Thank you :)

Comment: In the PHP error must be the answer. Can you post it?

Comment: This is a logic question, there is no error corretge.

Comment: Brian, what is "/frontpage/"? Is there an actual directory there with an index file you want to serve? Do you want to redirect the visitor to that /frontpage/ or just send the content of that file at the current URL (/)?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is have a different index than the one it wants to call from the /content/ folder. It will call index.php from the /content/ folder and place it where the body contents usually are. I want to actually want it to call a different page all together, because the index.php I want to use has a different layout than than the /content/index.php, which is just going to be text. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_contents instat of include.
Just check if it is an external URL.
And think of the Security. Maybe you can get Access to some config files ore something without checking $_GET['p'].

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with PHP alone, as the web server needs to know what to do with that url. If you're using Apache you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to alias example.com/frontpage to where the frontpage PHP script actually is.

Another option is to create a `frontpage` directory in the document root and add `index.php` to that directory, then make index.php load the actual frontpage (or just have index.php hold the frontpage content).

EDIT: I probably misunderstood the question: If you want that script to load the default page from another directory, you can do:

```
if( $page == $default ) {
    include( 'path/to/frontpage/file.php' );
}
else {
    include('content/'.$page.'.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should do:

```
<?php 
$default = 'about'; //Whatever default page you want to display if the file doesn't exist or you've just arrived to the home page. 
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : $default; //Checks if ?p is set, and puts the page in and if not, it goes to the default page. 
$page = basename($page); //Gets the page name only, and no directories. 
if (!file_exists('content/'.$page.'.php'))    { //Checks if the file doesn't exist 
    $page = $default; //If it doesn't, it'll revert back to the default page 
    //NOTE: Alternatively, you can make up a 404 page, and replace $default with whatever the page name is. Make sure it's still in the inc/ directory. 
}
else {
    $page = 'content/'.$page.'.php';
}
include($page); //And now it's on your page! 
?>
```

I should, however, mention that this is a bad idea. Instead of just including the file if it exists, you should instead limit it to a whitelist. Like `if (in_array($page,array('frontpage,'about',...)) ...`.